# Why maxMerge() gives different results than max() of sumMerge()?

Tags: clickhouse

The whole point is to get peaks per period (e.g. 5m peaks) for value that accumulates. So it needs to be summed per period and then the peak (maximum) can be found in those sums. (`select max(v) from (select sum(v) from t group by a1, a2)`)

---

I have a base table `t`.

Data are inserted into `t`, consider two attributes (time `t1` and some string `a2`) and one numeric value.

Value accumulates so it needs to be summed to get the total volume over certain period. Example of rows inserted:

```
t1     | a2 | v
----------------
date1  | b  | 1
date2  | c  | 20
```

---

I'm using a MV to compute `sumState()` and from that I get peaks using `sumMerge()` and then `max()`.

I need it only for max values so I was wondering I could use `maxState()` directly.

---

So this is what I do now: I use MV that computes a 5m sum and from that I read `max()`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sums_table ON CLUSTER '{cluster}' (
    t1              DateTime,
    a2              String,
    v               AggregateFunction(sum, UInt32)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree(
    '...',
    '{replica}'
)
    PARTITION BY toDate(t1) 
    ORDER BY (a2, t1)
    PRIMARY KEY (a2);
```

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mv_a
    ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
    TO sums_table
AS
SELECT toStartOfFiveMinute(t1) AS t1, a2,
    sumState(toUInt32(v)) AS v
FROM t
GROUP BY t1, a2
```

from that I'm able to read max of 5m sum for `a2` using

```sql
SELECT
    a2,
    max(sum) AS max
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1,
        a2,
        sumMerge(v) AS sum
    FROM sums_table
    WHERE t1 BETWEEN :fromDateTime AND :toDateTime
    GROUP BY t1, a2
)
GROUP BY a2
ORDER BY max DESC
```

That works perfectly.

---

So I wanted to achieve the same using `maxState` and `maxMerge()`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS max_table ON CLUSTER '{cluster}' (
    t1              DateTime,
    a2              String,
    max_v           AggregateFunction(max, UInt32)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedAggregatingMergeTree(
    '...',
    '{replica}'
)
    PARTITION BY toDate(t1) 
    ORDER BY (a2, t1)
    PRIMARY KEY (a2)
```

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mv_b
    ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
    TO max_table
AS
SELECT
    t1,
    a2
    maxState(v) AS max_v
FROM (
    SELECT
        toStartOfFiveMinute(t1) AS t1,
        a2,
        toUInt32(sum(v)) AS v
    FROM t
    GROUP BY t1, a2
)
GROUP BY t1, a2
```

and I thought if I get a max per time (t1) and a2, and then select max of that per a2, I'd get the maximum value for each a2, but I'm getting totally different max values using this query compared to the max of sums mentioned above.

```sql
SELECT
    a2,
    max(max) AS max
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1,
        a2,
        maxMerge(v) AS max
    FROM max_table
    WHERE t1 BETWEEN :fromDateTime AND :toDateTime
    GROUP BY t1, a2
) maxs_per_time_and_a2
GROUP BY a2
```

---

What did I do wrong? Do I get MVs wrong? Is it possible to use `maxState` with `maxMerge` for 2+ attributes to compute max over a longer period, let's say year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1,
    a2
    maxState(v) AS max_v
FROM (
    SELECT
        toStartOfFiveMinute(t1) AS t1,
        a2,
        toUInt32(sum(v)) AS v
    FROM t
    GROUP BY t1, a2
)
GROUP BY t1, a2
```

This is incorrect. And impossible.
Because MV is an insert trigger. It never reads REAL table `t`.
You are getting max from sum of rows in insert buffer.

If you insert 1 row with `v=10`. You will get max_v = 10. MatView does not "know" that a previous insert has added some rows, their sum is not taken into account.

Comment: Ah, so it's not really viable to use `maxState` to aggregate a max from a source table, right? Or any aggregate functions are basically not very usable with MVs and MV is rather for data filtering. I can only imagine summing sumMerges 

Comment: No. Only double aggregation with  different aggregate functions is not viable. maxState works perfectly in MV.